# Ruby closing program window on Windows 7

Tags: ruby

I've download Ruby using rubyinstaller. Apps closed itself after finishing executing, so i put gets at the end of it - it works, but if there is an error it closes, and I have problem with debugging. How can i prevent this?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Ruby. It's a basic Windows user question. It's been a long time since I used Windows, so my memory is a bit fuzzy, but basically, there is a checkbox in the program properties that says "close Window on exit" or something similar. Uncheck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way is to run your Ruby program from console (command line).

An alternative hack is to wrap your main program in an exception handler:

```
begin
  ... your code here ...

rescue => exc
  puts "#{exc.class}: #{exc}"   # write exception message
  puts exc.backtrace.join "\n"  # write backtrace
  gets                          # wait for Return
end
```

Comment: It's nice piece of advice, but it would be nicer if it included exceptions class insteap of generic "Error: ", so it basicly looked like default Ruby error print.

Comment: @Borsunho: Like this?

Comment: Exactly. This is important information if user of this hack later decided that he needs to `rescue` such exception instead of somehow preventing it (for whatever reason).